# RichTextBox Bullet Points Alignment Display Issue (Left, Centre, and Right)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, forms, winforms, richtextbox

I have the following display problem when entering my 'email composure' form:

[image: Bullets incorrectly aligned]

I have left, centre, and right aligned bullet points. To make the selected text bullet point list style, a button is activated which does the following:

```
chkBullet.CheckState = If(isSelectionBulletList(richTextBox), CheckState.Checked, CheckState.Unchecked)
```

Which in turn, activates the paragraph as a bullet list:

```
Private Function isSelectionBulletList(RichTextBox As RichTextBox) As Boolean
Dim startParagraph As Paragraph = RichTextBox.Selection.Start.Paragraph
If startParagraph IsNot Nothing Then
  If TypeOf (startParagraph.Parent) Is ListItem Then
    Dim markerStyle As TextMarkerStyle = CType(startParagraph.Parent, ListItem).List.MarkerStyle
    If markerStyle = TextMarkerStyle.Disc Then
      Return True
    End If
  End If
End If
Return False
End Function
```

To move the highlighted bullet points to the desired alignment, I am running the following:

```
 Align(0).Checked =
  (CType(richTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Paragraph.TextAlignmentProperty), TextAlignment) =
   TextAlignment.Left)
```

Which correctly moves the text, but does not move the bullet with the text.

I later run a RTF to HTML conversion later and send off the email to my inbox, and the bullet points are aligned correctly, as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this display issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though there is not an immediate fix to this problem.

A more experienced colleague has suggested that a workaround for this issue would be to create a **custom WPF control**, using a **RichTextBox**, in it's place.

See here for the known issue, according to the Microsoft forum thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/efbd8f0a-4f6d-4e7b-8988-cc17a02e354b/wpf-applying-alignment-to-a-list-in-a-rich-text-box?forum=wpf